# Macro to delete all repeated instances of text in word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for a simple way to delete repeated text in a Word 2007 document.  If there are some shortcuts with the Find/Replace commands, I'm not seeing it.  Otherwise, can someone recommend how I might write a macro that works like the following:

1- Select a block of text (could be mulitple paragraphs, have bullet points, etc).
2- Run the macro or do the command.
3- The macro or command deletes all instances of the selected text block.

Any insight here?

Comment: I don't like deleting questions when people have taken the time and effort to help you.  Please upvote answers that helped and select the one that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Selection.Text* returns the current selection's text.

In principle, the syntax for your Replace command is:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = Selection.Text
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

You replace by an empty string, thus delete every instance of the text to find.

But: You have to decide of course how to handle the formatting of the selected text, maybe have to analyze your selected block first because replacing might not work with control chars neglected by *Selection.Text* ... This is just the start, you need to specify what you want and then ask again, yourself or us. Meanwhile *Record macro* and the word vba reference are your friends.

Comment: I have a mail-merged form letter, and I want to delete all the text that is the same and pull out the addresses.  so I want to delete everything in that selection, and every copy of it throughout the document.  I'm not sure what it is I need to specify further?

Comment: Your requirement is clearer now than it was in your original post. So you want to delete occurences of text regardless of any formatting? I am sure though that you can find your solution with the hints given and I am also sure that you work on a copy of your document while testing and finding out the smaller issues.

Answer (score 0):

For alpha number text (with out newlines), you can use Find/Replace however as soon as you get in the realm of bullets, new paragraphs, etc. it will no longer do exact matching. If you often need to do that, I would suggest using a program like LaTeX to write your documents. LaTeX would allow you do this style of exact matching of large blocks of text. If you're on a Windows machine, a great LaTeX package would be proTeXt which can be found at http://www.tug.org/protext/

Comment: Unfourtunatly, I have to do it in word.  My only other real option is to go through and manually delete this information on 96 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, huge mailing list and I just needed the emails. I solved it by copying the text in excel, filtering sentence by sentence (or bullets) the paragraph i wanted to remove and deleting all rows. Mine was more than 270 pages, worked just fine (as long as the text is not too long, it was a lot faster than replaceing sentence by sentence in word.) Or if it is an option, just filter with a text filter - begins with "to:" , then you are done in 10 secs. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think they're looking for a more automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just Press Ctrl+H to select and replace text, Type the text you want to remove and Press Replace All leaving  replace with field BLANK

Comment: I don't think it would work for very large part of text (100's of pages).